# Data Studio SYSTEM_ERROR Code 13 with SQL query

Tags: sql, looker-studio

```sql
SELECT user_leads.id, 
       first_name                              AS 'Nombres', 
       last_name                               AS 'Apellidos', 
       ip                                      AS 'IP o número de telefono', 
       city                                    AS 'Ciudad', 
       state                                   AS 'Estado', 
       From_unixtime(user_leads.timestamp)     AS 'Fecha', 
       Count(wadmin.id)                        AS 'Total Grupos de Whatsapp (Admin)', 
       Coalesce(Group_concat(wadmin.name), '') AS 'Grupos de Whatsapp (Admin)', 
       lead_sources.name                       AS 'Fuente', 
       lead_statuses.name                      AS 'Status', 
       dw.session_id 
FROM   user_leads 
       LEFT JOIN dialogflow_sessions AS dw 
              ON dw.lead_id = user_leads.id 
       LEFT JOIN user_lead_global_fields AS gf_ans 
              ON gf_ans.leadid = user_leads.id 
       LEFT JOIN lead_sources 
              ON lead_sources.id = sourceid 
       LEFT JOIN lead_statuses 
              ON lead_statuses.id = user_leads.statusid 
       LEFT JOIN whatsapp_groups AS wadmin 
              ON wadmin.admin_lead_id = user_leads.id 
GROUP  BY user_leads.id 
ORDER  BY user_leads.id DESC
```

Im currently using that query, here is what I tried

1. Removing special characters
2. Removing "as *" statements
3. clearing cache
4. changing sql data source and double checked my connection yet nothing

[image]

[image]

Has anyone faced this issue?

Comment: What's your data source? (What database?) Anyway, your query seems too complex. Did you try to simplify the query to detect what makes it raise this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it. Data Studio doesn't like spaces in column aliases, yet it won't show any error for them. The working is the same with all spaces in aliases replaced by underscore